# Get directory/file structure without payload from FTP server

Tags: bash, unix, ftp, wget, curl

I need to recursively retrieve the file/directory structure of an FTP server, getting only file names (without payload). Can you help me how to do this? (`curl`, `wget`, …).

The result should be the directory tree with all files with 0 size, but also a text file with file/dir list can be good.

I tried to use the `.listing` generated by `wget` but it's too much verbose (I need only file name with full path).

Comment: Better gives sample inputs/outputs

Answer (score 0):

A basic aproach :

```
lftp -u user,passwd domain.tld -e 'nlist *; quit' | awk '$5 == 0'
```

Answer (score 0):

If [`curlftpfs`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/curlftpfs) is available for you, use it (see [this another answer of mine](https://superuser.com/a/1292278/432690)). You will be able to browse the remote directory tree as if it was local.

Tools like `cp` will work, so if you really need a local copy of the directory tree without the payload, use this command:

```
cp -R --attributes-only /curlftpfs/mountpoint/ /some/local/path/
```

<sub>(Note: `--attributes-only` is not required by POSIX, your `cp` may or may not understand it).</sub>