# How to recursively search FTP server using Linux?

Tags: linux, ftp, dd-wrt

I googled this and found tons of answers, but for one reason or another they just didn't work for me or wouldn't fit the situation. I run DD-WRT third party firmware on my routers. Occasionally I want to update one and need to find the newest firmware so I will have to go manually search `ftp.dd-wrt.com`. I found a way to use Google to search the repo recursively, but it's picky. I can google using the query below and it finds some but is very picky.

```
site:ftp.dd-wrt.com ROUTERMODELNUM
```

Is there a way to do recursive searches of an FTP server? Even recursively displaying files in a FTP server and then using grep to filter would be acceptable to me.

Comment: I won't say that there isn't such a tool  (we don't do software recommendations either way) but that kind of task is completely inconsistent with the FTP command syntax, so Id be a little surprised.

Comment: Yes, i didn't see ftp commands that could do it so i was wondering if there was a hybrid way like my Google search. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`curlftpfs`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/curlftpfs).

> The program `curlftpfs` is a tool to mount remote ftp hosts as local directories.

This is a [FUSE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filesystem_in_Userspace)-based solution, get familiar with [security concerns](https://www.cs.nmsu.edu/~pfeiffer/fuse-tutorial/html/security.html). You can (and should) do the mounting as a normal user:

```
curlftpfs -r ftp.dd-wrt.com ~/mnt/foo/
```

Then play with `find` or whatever. To unmount:

```
fusermount -u ~/mnt/foo/
```