# Is there a way to print filename with path from SFTP in Unix server?

Tags: bash, unix, shell, sftp

I am trying to print file names along with path from SFTP server to other location. I am able to get file names but not path. Below is the code that I have used:

```
echo "ls *.gpg" | sftp xfer@nsb.abc.com:/SXMPMX/INBOUND/FORDCOI_CONT_RESP > $Path/sample.txt
```

Please let me know is there any way to solve my problem.

Answer (score 0):

In general many things can get easier with [FUSE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filesystem_in_Userspace).

Use FUSE and deal with paths locally, using local tools like `find`. This is very similar to [my another answer about FTP](https://superuser.com/a/1292278/432690), you just need [`sshfs`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/sshfs) instead of `curlftpfs`.

Having a SFTP share mounted under e.g. `/some/mountpoint/`, `cd` to where you want and use

```
realpath --relative-to /some/mountpoint/ *.gpg
```

Example:

```
$ sshfs xfer@nsb.abc.com:/ /some/mountpoint/
$ cd /some/mountpoint/SXMPMX/INBOUND/FORDCOI_CONT_RESP
$ realpath --relative-to /some/mountpoint/ foo.gpg   # assuming the file exists
SXMPMX/INBOUND/FORDCOI_CONT_RESP/foo.gpg
```

Comment: In local i can able to print file name with path by using readlink -f *.txt command. i wanted to print the file name and path from SFTP.