# Move all files in local directory to remote SFTP directory

Tags: linux, bash, ssh, sftp, scp

I want to move all files in local directory to remote directory.

And I am using this code to achieve it

```
SOURCE_FILE=/var/www/oneserver/*
TARGET_DIR=/var/www/anotherServer
ARCHIEVEFILE=/var/www/archieveServer

/usr/bin/expect<<EOD
spawn /usr/bin/sftp -o Port=$PORT $USER@$HOST
expect "password:"
send "$PASSWORD\r"
expect "sftp>"
send "put $SOURCE_FILE $TARGET_DIR\r"
expect "sftp>"
send "bye\r"
EOD
```

It works fine, but sometime it stops and only send some files.

I also want to move the already sent file to `ARCHIEVEFILE` by using `mv` command. But don't get idea how to move it. I can't use SCP because the remote server not allowed using basic port, and the only way is using SFTP.

- the `$ARCHIEVEFILE` is still the local server, just to backup/move so those files are not sent anymore with next cronjob
- the `TARGET_DIR` is the remote server.

Can anybody help, please?

Answer (score 2):

There's no command in OpenSSH `sftp` to *move* files to remote directory.

What you can do is to:

- use `sftp` `put` to upload the files (as you are doing already), and then
- use [shell `rm` command](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/rm.1.html) to delete the files *after `sftp` is done* (i.e. after `EOD`):

  ```
  rm $SOURCE_FILE
  ```

  Or use [`!` to escape to shell](https://man.openbsd.org/sftp#!) *from `sftp` script*, after you sent `put`:

  ```
  send "!rm $SOURCE_FILE\r"
  expect "sftp>"
  ```

---

*Of course, this is not an atomic solution. If a file is added between `put` and `rm`, it will be lost. For an atomic solution, you have to iterate files in a local directory and upload and delete them one by one. Also for a robust solution, you need to check if an upload was successful.*

Answer (score 1):

The following approach may simplify things a lot:

1. Use [`sshfs`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/sshfs) to mount the remote share(s) as local path(s).
2. Work with `cp` and/or `mv` as if all operations were local.

Compare [this answer of mine](https://superuser.com/a/1293067/432690).

You still need some logic to detect if `cp` to the remote location succeeded, only then `mv` to the local archive; otherwise retry or something. But now all SFTP-related work should be transparently handled by `sshfs`.

Additionally shell globbing and quotes you use makes your code prone to errors related to spaces in filenames etc.

After you mount the remote share e.g. in `/mnt/a b/remote`, it will be so much easier to handle this.

(Note: [it is a good practice to use lowercase variable names](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/42849/108618)).

- To mount:

  ```
  sshfs -p $port $user@$host:"/path/on/the/remote/host/" "/mnt/a b/remote/"
  ```

  Use key based authentication or read [Username and password in command line with sshfs](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/337465/108618). Read about [security concerns](https://www.cs.nmsu.edu/~pfeiffer/fuse-tutorial/html/security.html).
- A code stub to copy files:

  ```
  # I deliberately use paths with spaces to show how to handle them
  for filename in "/source/location with spaces"/*; do
     cp "$filename" "/mnt/a b/remote/" &&
     mv "$filename" "/archive/location with spaces/"
  done
  ```

  This `&&` ensures `mv` will run only if `cp` succeeds.
- To unmount:

  ```
  fusermount -u "/mnt/a b/remote/"
  ```

Comment: the `$ARCHIEVEFILE` is still the local server, just to backup/move so those files are not sent anymore with next cronjob.

Comment: the `TARGET_DIR` is the remote server.

Comment: I update my question. Please have a look. The real problem I encounter with this script is it only send some files, not all files.

Comment: I am sorry late respond, I am actually still confuse how to combine your answer `for filename in ...` with the script I have right now `send "put $SOURCE_FILE $TARGET_DIR\r"`. As far as I know you use `cp` method, while I used `put` and `expect ` method.

Comment: @klaudia My approach it totally different and it requires you to mount the share with `sshfs`.

Comment: This will force me to learn how to connect to server with sshfs too, and check if able to connect to specific port with that. If you can point me to some good example, that will be an added to me.

Comment: @klaudia My answer is now expanded. Remember that `man 1 sshfs` is your friend.

Comment: I am not sure what `to mount` is. hehe This is returning bad mount point`sshfs -p $port $user@$host:/ "/my/local/files/in/dir/ /remote/dir/to/transfer"`

Comment: @klaudia The basic syntax is `sshfs user@host:dir mountpoint`, e.g. `sshfs klaudia@server:/home/klaudia/ "/local mountpoint/that has to exist beforehand/"`.

Comment: I tried that, but it said `Transport endpoint is not connected`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/76265/discussion-between-klaudia-and-kamil-maciorowski).

Answer (score 0):

You could zip the source directory you wish to transfer

```
zip -r -9 /path/to/your/zip_file.zip var/www/oneserver/*
```

(-r will recurse into subdirs
 , -9 will apply maximum compression for quicker transfer)

then scp the file to your remote server

```
scp /path/to/your/zip_file.zip user@host:/var/www/anotherServer
```

and then unzip the file on the remote server

```
ssh user@host 'unzip /var/www/anotherServer/zip_file.zip'
```

(there are many flags you can use with unzip  you can use to overwrite or never overwrite exsiting files on your remote server, check man unzip for them  , especially -n -o and -u )

hope it helps you