# How to copy ALL files in a directory to remote without directory?

Tags: ssh, unix, ftp, scp

I want to copy all files including "hidden" `.` files from a directory `output` to a remote directory `target` using scp. Alternatives welcome except `rsync`. Unfortunately the hosting provider won't allow its installation.

I have looked up several solutions and it seems harder than what I expected.

---

```
scp -P 22 -r path/to/output/ "$USER@$HOST:/path/target/"
```

and

```
scp -P 22 -r path/to/output "$USER@$HOST:/path/target/"
```

put files to `/path/target/output/` or requires renaming.

---

```
scp -P 22 -r path/to/output/* "$USER@$HOST:/path/target/"
```

This does not match hidden files.

---

```
scp -P 22 -r path/to/output/. "$USER@$HOST:/path/target/"
```

This no longer works (details in comment to https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/232947 ).

---

```
scp -P 22 -r path/to/output/{,.[!.],..?}* "$USER@$HOST:/path/target/"
```

This will fail in case not all patterns have a match (e.g. missing files of the form `.<filename>`.

---

I am looking for a way to just copy *all* contents of a directory recursively to a remote directory. I have SSH or FTP access. Bonus would be to clean the target dir before copying.

Edit: leaving the trailing slash for `target` has no impact

Comment: [`sshfs`](https://superuser.com/a/1315346/432690).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am using a solution found [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/106508) that uses `ssh` and `tar`:

```
tar -C path/to/output/ -cf - . | ssh $USER@$HOST tar -C path/target/ -xvf -
```

This tells `tar` to change to `path/to/output/` archive to `-` (std) and include all (`.`) files then pipes it to unpack to remote where `tar` changes to the target output dir before unpacking.

Comment: Same solution I usually use.

Answer (score 1):

You can use bash's nullglob option to skip unmatched wildcards:

```
shopt -s nullglob
scp -P 22 -r path/to/output/{,.[!.],..?}* "$USER@$HOST:/path/target/"
shopt -u nullglob    # Put it back to normal afterward!
```

One possible problem with this is that if the directory is entirely empty (i.e. none of the wildcard branches match anything), the entire argument vanishes and `scp` complains because you didn't give it both a source and a target. If this is possible, store the file list in an array and check for contents first:

```
shopt -s nullglob
filesToSend=( path/to/output/{,.[!.],..?}* )
shopt -u nullglob    # Put it back to normal afterward!
if (( ${#filesToSend[@]} > 0 )); then
    scp -P 22 -r "${filesToSend[@]}" "$USER@$HOST:/path/target/"
else
    echo "No files in source directory" >&2
fi
```