# "find" using LFTP tries to access arguments

Tags: linux, find, sftp, lftp

I connect via `lftp -u username, sftp://server.name.com:/directory` to a *sftp*-server, which works correctly.

Anyhow, I want to use `find. -name *someWildcardExpression -type f -delete` in order to delete all files in the directory as well as subdirectories. Actually, `find` finds all relevant files. However, it also tries to access directories created by the arguments passed to `find`:

```bsh
lftp username@server.name.com:/directory> find . -name *someWildcardExpression -type f

# Output
./
./file_a.csv.gz.gpg
./subdir/
./subdir/file_a.csv.gz.gpg
./subdir/file_b.csv.gz.gpg
./subdir/file_c.csv.gz.gpg
find: No such file (/directory/-name)
find: No such file (/directory/*someWildcardExpression )
find: No such file (/directory/-type)
find: No such file (/directory/f)
```

This does not seem right.
Am I using the `find`-command wrong, or is this a bug?

Comment: Try `find . -regex '*someWildcardExpression' -type f` (attention before using `-delete`).

Comment: Unfortunately, this also results in the analog error: `find: No such file (/directory/-regex)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Am I using the `find`-command wrong, or is this a bug?

You're using it wrong because it's not the `find`-command you think it is. You're inside `lftp`, not in a general-purpose shell. You're **not** invoking `find(1)` compatible with [POSIX `find`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/find.html), whose manual you can read by running `man 1 find` in a shell. You're invoking a part of `lftp` whose [manual](https://lftp.tech/lftp-man.html) reads:

> `find [OPTS] directory...`
>
> List  files  in the directory (current directory by default) recursively.  This can help with servers lacking `ls -R` support. You can redirect output of this command.
>
> Options:
>
> `-d MD`, `--max-depth=MD`  specify maximum scan depth
> `-l`, `--ls` use long listing format

There are no other options. That's why every "option" you used was treated like a directory.

`lftp` allows you to run an arbitrary shell command by prepending the command with `!`, but it will run the command locally (where `lftp` runs), not on the server. It seems you want to run `find` on the server.

This is what you can do:

1. Use `find` inside `lftp` without syntax it doesn't understand, parse its output locally to imitate `-name *someWildcardExpression -type f`. You probably can imitate `-name` by matching the string after the last non-trailing `/` in each line. You cannot fully imitate `-type f`, but it seems you can imitate `! -type d` (it seems directories are printed with a trailing slash), ask yourself if it's enough.
2. If you can `ssh` to the server, use it to run the server's `find(1)`.
3. [Use `sshfs` to make the remote directory appear local](https://superuser.com/a/1315346/432690), then invoke *local* `find(1)`.