# Is there a way to create a multipart archive in multiple sessions?

Tags: backup, filesystems, network-shares, file-sharing, nfs

I have a remote machine, where the space is very limited (~15GB free)
I have an NFS share mounted on this VM, the size of the share is ~600GBs.
The NFS share has lightning-fast access from this machine.

I want to bring 600GB of files in the above share, to my local system (over internet) for offline use. (Chunked as may be 2GB archives using http or off-the-shelf tools - dropbox/onedrive)
My local system has a slow access to this share. I have tried rsync -ing it to a local folder after mounting as NFS, But it goes on for ever - may be since it has millions of files.

Since the remote machine has less free space,
Is there a way to create an incremental archive of the NFS share files in multiple sessions (Can restart archive creation after freeing up space.)

Environment:

1. Local system is Mac
2. The remote VM is Ubuntu

Local machine has ~ 1TB of free space.

I looked at tar/zpaq but they don't seem to have the necessary features.
Is there any faster solution than writing a custom script?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is `sshfs` available on Mac? I found this: [macFUSE](https://osxfuse.github.io). With `sshfs` you can [use `cp`](https://superuser.com/a/1315346/432690) or whatever. I believe the fact NFS is involved is irrelevant. I believe if the files are available after you `ssh` to the remote VM then you can reach them with `sshfs` instead.

Comment: This again depends on the not so fast network. 
The reason why I am looking for archives are primarily because of the efficient transfers. Individual files over SSH/NFS/rsyc etc. are prohibitively slow.

Comment: Is the 600GB in one or more files? If in several files, how large are they? Do they contain text?

Comment: @harrymc mainly executables, libraries, build tools. Large no. of  individual files.

Comment: How will you be bringing the files over? (Network from remote to local? Sneakernet?) Does the archive have to be _compressed_, or does it just need to hold many files?

Comment: @NSGopikrishnan: Zipping binary files is not efficient. If both machines have `rsync` or anything similar, you could do the transfer at about the same speed. Zipping won't get you a big improvement. (Add to your comment `@harrymc` for me to be notified.)

Comment: Zipping/any archive format is just to get them to equal file sizes, maybe 2GB, No compression opted. Just to chunk it for the download. I will be moving it through Onedrive. @harrymc

Comment: You may use [rclone](https://rclone.org/) to sync to *and from* OneDrive. You can't do chunks since you don't have the space to compress the 600GB into one archive.

Comment: Is it faster than mounting the NFS locally and rsync -ing it from mounted to local folder? If the no. of files remain huge(a million+), I think it will be too much overhead. I am coming across rclone for the first time @harrymc

Comment: [rclone mount](https://rclone.org/commands/rclone_mount/) mounts the remote as file system on a mountpoint. This will allow you to zip the whole thing in one go to OneDrive, but with any interruption you will have to restart from the beginning. I don't recommend this as the gains will be minor.