# How to "get" multiple directories from an SFTP server

Tags: linux, openssh, sftp

I have an SFTP server with the following directories:

```
dir1
test_results
templates
```

How can I get everything inside these directories as is to my local?

I tried:

```
get -r dir1 test_results templates
```

But it is considering the `test_results` as a directory in side the local machine and put the `dir1` inside it.

Can someone help me?

Comment: See the first three sentences of [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/1315346/432690).

Answer (score 4):

Just issue separate `get` command for each directory.

```
get -R dir1
get -R test_results
get -R templates
```

The [OpenSSH `sftp` `get` command](https://man.openbsd.org/sftp#get) accepts one mandatory source remote-path parameter and one optional target local-path parameter. Nothing more.

For recursive download, the official switch is `-R` (`-r` is just an undocumented alias).