# wget FTP: how to recursively download a whole directory WITHOUT .listing files?

Tags: linux, ftp, download, wget

I want to download a whole directory from my FTP server, and it can be done by using `wget` with `-m` option.

```
wget -m --ftp-user=aaaa --ftp-password=bbbb ftp://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/dir
```

However, I noticed that `.listing` files are created under all directories, and I don't want these files.  I learned that `wget` has the option `--no-remove-listing`, but it seems there is no option to do the opposite.  Is it possible to mirror directories without creating the `.listing` files?  Or, is there any better tool than `wget`?

Comment: "is there any better tool than `wget`?" – This sentence makes your question prone to being closed as off-topic because software recommendations are off-topic here on Super User. You may consider removing it ([edit] the question), especially since there is a solution using `wget`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I learned that `wget` has the option `--no-remove-listing`, but it seems there is no option to do the opposite.

There's no need for such option. You just don't use `--no-remove-listing`. In your case this option is implicitly set because of `-m`.

From [`man 1 wget`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/wget):

> `-m`
>   `--mirror`
>   Turn on options suitable for mirroring. This option turns on recursion and time-stamping, sets infinite recursion depth and keeps FTP directory listings. It is currently equivalent to `-r -N -l inf --no-remove-listing`.

Conclusion: instead of `-m` use equivalent options *without* `--no-remove-listing`, i.e. `-r -N -l inf`:

```
wget -r -N -l inf --ftp-user=aaaa --ftp-password=bbbb ftp://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/dir
```

---

Another approach: `curlftpfs` (with `cp` or whatever). See [this answer of mine](https://superuser.com/a/1292278/432690).