# How can I set my default Download folder to be my ftp server? (Linux)

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ftp, default-settings

I have a Linux Ubuntu laptop on which I download a lot of movies and I want it to transfer movies that have finished downloading to my ftp server. I tried doing it like this:

```
xdg-user-dirs-update --set DOWNLOAD 192.168.0.23:21/volume9
```

or like this:

```
xdg-user-dirs-update --set DOWNLOAD ftp://192.168.0.23:21/volume9
```

but I got an error:

```
directory value must be absolute path (was 192.168.0.23:21/volume9)
```

Is there a way I can do this?

Comment: *directory value must be absolute path* like ftp:....... perhaps? Probably the port number isn't necessary.

Comment: @MichaelBay I tried that and without port number and it didn't work

Comment: Can you open and save a file to ftp://.................. using the file manager?

Comment: @MichaelBay yes I can

Comment: What about sharing the volume on SMB and mounting it? You should then be able to specify an absolute path like `/media/ftpvol`. Or even down-load direct into this volume.

Comment: Just [mount the FTP share](https://superuser.com/a/1292278/432690) in your local directory tree.

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/1312688/can-a-remote-location-on-a-server-be-the-default-download-directory