# Is there an alternative command or way to speed up find in LFTP?

Tags: linux, command-line, find, lftp

There is an FTP server I'm connecting to, and it could possibly have 20-30k zip files and an assortment of subdirectories. I would like to return a list of all of these files based on their extension, so *.zip. I've ran a simple enough find command from shell to match on the extension only, and it did have a speed enhancement. When I am LFTP'd into the server however, the find command isn't the same as the one from the generic shell.

This:
`find . | grep -Fi .zip`
Changed to this(2x faster): `find /directory -name "*.zip"`

Manual:

> `find [OPTS] directory...`
>
> List  files  in the directory (current directory by default) recursively.  This can help with servers lacking `ls -R` support. You can redirect output of this command.
>
> Options:
>
> `-d MD`, `--max-depth=MD`  specify maximum scan depth
> `-l`, `--ls` use long listing format

Is there a way in LFTP to get a list of files back and filter on file name extensions?

Comment: *Maybe* [this approach](https://superuser.com/a/1292278/432690) can help.

Comment: lftp supports the ls command as well, which allows for piping. You could also "find . > output.txt" and grep that file.