# Delete all directories on a ftp folder except ones I list cronjob?

Tags: linux, bash, ftp, cron

Is there any way for me to delete all folders in a given ftp folder using a cronjob, and the deleted files are folders older than x hours, with a few specific folders that are not deleted that I specify before hand? I've tried/spent a few hours looking around and I can't find anything that matches what I need and i'm pretty green to all of this.

I was previously doing it using a bash script and a find function on my server, but now that I want to do it via ftp nothing is working. I don't have admin/root rights on the server im trying to connect to.

Comment: Yes it's probably possible. What have you tried? What research have you done?

Comment: I think one possible approach starts with [`curlftpfs`](https://superuser.com/a/1292278/432690), uses `find` and ends with `fusermount -u`.

Comment: awesome thank you! I will try to look into curlftpfs more